# javascript getElementsByClassName change value of text fields

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make the values of all the text fields with a certain class name update each other, I mean, if you have 2 text fields with class="a", and I type something in one text field, the other one will update with what I typed. This is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function run()
        {
            var eq     = document.getElementById("Energyq");
            var m      = document.getElementsByClassName("mass");
            var cHeat  = document.getElementById("cHeat");
            var dT     = document.getElementById("deltaTemprature");
            var ek     = document.getElementById("Energyk");
            var v      = document.getElementById("velocity");
            var gc     = document.getElementById("gravityCoefficient")

        function classUpdate(class, changedId)
        {
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName(class);
            var temp = x[changedId].value;
            for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
                x[i].value = temp.value;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <table style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 35px" border="10">
            <tr style="text-align: center">
                <td>Eq</td><td> = </td><td>m<td> * </td></td><td>c<td> * </td></td><td>ΔT</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="text-align: center">
                <td><input type="number" type="number" style="max-width: 105px" id="Energyq" class="energy" /></td><td> = </td><td><input type="number" style="max-width: 105px"  max="10" class="mass" id="mass1" onkeyup="classUpdate("mass",1)" onchange="classUpdate("mass",1)" /></td><td> * </td><td><input type="number" style="max-width: 105px" id="cHeat"  /></td><td> * </td><td><input type="number" style="max-width: 105px" id="deltaTemprature"  /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center">Ek</td><td style="text-align: center"> = </td><td style="text-align: left">(m</td><td style="text-align: center">*</td><td style="text-align: right">v² )</td><td style="text-align: center"> /</td><td style="text-align: center"> 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="text-align: center">
                <td><input type="number" style="max-width: 105px" id="Energyk" class="energy" /></td><td> = </td><td>(<input type="number" style="max-width: 105px" max="10" class="mass" id="mass2" h="10" onkeyup="classUpdate("mass",2)" onchange="classUpdate("mass",2)" /></td><td> * </td><td><input type="number" style="max-width: 105px" id="velocity"  /><font size="6.5">²</font> )</td><td> /</td><td> 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="text-align: center">
                <td>Eh</td><td> = </td><td>m</td><td> * </td><td>g</td><td> * </td><td>h</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="text-align: center">
                <td><input type="number" style="max-width: 105px" id="Energyh" class="energy"  /></td><td> = </td><td><input type="number" style="max-width: 105px" max="10" class="mass" id="mass3"  onkeyup="classUpdate("mass",3)" onchange="classUpdate("mass",3)" /></td><td> * </td><td><input type="number" style="max-width: 105px" id="gravitatinalCoefficient"  /></td><td> * </td><td><input type="number" style="max-width: 105px" id="height"  /></td>
            </tr>
        <br />
        </table>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="massConservation" /> Conservation of mass</label> 
        <br />
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="energyConservation" /> Conservation of energy</label> 
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="reset" /> <input type="button" onclick="run()" value="Calculate" />

        <h6>by X</h6>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot handle return value of getElementById and getElementsByClassName the same way. Other is a single item, other is a collection that you have to iterate through.

There are multiple other problems in your code as well. One is to use a construct like this:

```
onkeyup="classUpdate("mass",1)"
```

which will not work due to problem with quotes, you need to have it like

```
onkeyup="classUpdate('mass',1)"
```

also, you have

```
        var temp = changedElem.value;
        ...
            x[i].value = temp.value;
```

which will not work as `temp` is a simple variable, it does not have a property named `value`.

---

What you really might want is

```
onkeyup="classUpdate('mass', this)"
```

and then a function like

```
    function classUpdate(className, changedElem)
    {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
        var temp = changedElem.value;
        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
            x[i].value = temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm talking about classUpdate(), the other part of the code isn't ready, I do iterate through it there.

Comment: @user2338361 why don't you edit the question then to only contain the part that you consider ready, relevant to the question and are having problems with. It's not clear what is the problem you're having.

Comment: @user2338361 added some updates to my answer. You still seem to have a lot of issues with the code, and the example snippet does not even run due to missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

```
function classUpdate(className, changedId)
{
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    var temp = x[changedId].value;
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        x[i].value = temp.value;
    }
}
```

I would update the class var to className, since "class" is a reserved word.

Comment: hmm... didn't change the result... nothing happened.

Comment: Im confused to what youre trying to do, but in my browser I got an error passing the params to the ClassUpdate function. I updated the code to single quote instead and got it to respond classUpdate('mass',2)

Comment: It does respond now, but for some reason it deletes the text(in chrome) and in firefox it says "undefined" in the text fields. So it does update them, but incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old but I could not find a good alternative answer that allowed a facility to shorthand ID (document.getElementById) and CLASS (document.getElementsByClassName).

I needed to implement a light version rather than use jquery or another plugin (you can see the test site [here](https://mortgage.icalculator.info/calculators/mortgage-calculator.html), Javascript can be seen in browser for application.

```
var $=function(a,b,c){b=a.substr(1);if(a.includes("#")){return document.getElementById(b);}else{c=document.getElementsByClassName(b);for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++){return c[i];}}};
```

You can then simply use:

```
b=$("#a").value; $("#za").innerHTML=a
```

etc to access the relevant value, html etc.  Clearly additional shorthand can be used to tighten this up but I have left like this for ease of comprehension on approach.

You could further extend this for your own minified library using:

```
function $v(a){return $(a).value;}
function $i(a){return $(a).innerHTML;}
```

allowing:

b=$("#a").value; $("#za").innerHTML=a

to become:

b=$v("#a");$i("#za")=a;

Which can be very useful for keeping the overhead down when building a project where you are better having your own lean framework rather than one filled with goodies which, although great, serve no purpose to the project and are just waste in terms of bandwodth.